# Difference between QuantileDiscretizer and Bucketizer in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This may be a novice question, however I'm unable to comprehend if there is any specific advantage of using `QuantileDiscretizer` over `Bucketizer`in spark 2.1 ?

I understand that `QuantileDiscretizer` is an estimator and handles NAN values whereas `Bucketizer` is a transformer and raises error if data has NAN values.

from the spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html) , below code produces similar outputs

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import QuantileDiscretizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

data = [(0, 18.0), (1, 19.0), (2, 8.0), (3, 5.0), (4, 2.2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "hour"])

result_discretizer = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=3, inputCol="hour",outputCol="result").fit(df).transform(df)
result_discretizer.show()

splits = [-float("inf"),3, 10,float("inf")]
result_bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=splits, inputCol="hour",outputCol="result").transform(df)
result_bucketizer.show()
```

Output :

```
+---+----+------+
| id|hour|result|
+---+----+------+
|  0|18.0|   2.0|
|  1|19.0|   2.0|
|  2| 8.0|   1.0|
|  3| 5.0|   1.0|
|  4| 2.2|   0.0|
+---+----+------+

+---+----+------+
| id|hour|result|
+---+----+------+
|  0|18.0|   2.0|
|  1|19.0|   2.0|
|  2| 8.0|   1.0|
|  3| 5.0|   1.0|
|  4| 2.2|   0.0|
+---+----+------+
```

Please let me know if there is any significant advantage of one over other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`QuantileDiscretizer` determines the bucket splits based on the data.

`Bucketizer` puts data into buckets that you specify via `splits`.

So use `Bucketizer` when you know the buckets you want, and `QuantileDiscretizer` to estimate the splits for you.

That the outputs are similar in the example is due to the contrived data and the `splits` chosen. Results may vary significantly in other scenarios.

Comment: could you answer the last question ? " significant advantage of one over other? Shouldnt there be a difference in accessing big data ? both are different strategies to make bins.

Comment: @Khan: Without any benchmarking, I'm guessing the `QuantileDiscretizer` is more expansive than the `Bucketizer`. As @ImDarrenG said, the former is a two-step process, first determine the quantiles (e.g. median, 75% etc) based on the distribution, then use the that as the bucket boundaries for `Bucketizer`, whereas the latter is just one step based on your input of boundaries.

Answer (score -2):

**QuantileDiscretizer** (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer) takes a column with continuous features and outputs a column with binned categorical features. The number of bins is set by the numBuckets parameter. It is possible that the number of buckets used will be smaller than this value, for example, if there are too few distinct values of the input to create enough distinct quantiles.

**Bucketizer** (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketizer) transforms a column of continuous features to a column of feature buckets, where the buckets are specified by users.

You can use both together like so:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import QuantileDiscretizer, Bucketizer

data = [(0, 18.0), (1, 19.0), (2, 8.0), (3, 5.0), (4, 2.2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "hour"])
print(df.show())

+---+----+
| id|hour|
+---+----+
|  0|18.0|
|  1|19.0|
|  2| 8.0|
|  3| 5.0|
|  4| 2.2|
+---+----+

qds = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=5, inputCol="hour", outputCol="buckets", relativeError=0.01, handleInvalid="error")
bucketizer = qds.fit(df)
bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("skip").transform(df).show()

+---+----+-------+
| id|hour|buckets|
+---+----+-------+
|  0|18.0|    3.0|
|  1|19.0|    3.0|
|  2| 8.0|    2.0|
|  3| 5.0|    2.0|
|  4| 2.2|    1.0|
+---+----+-------+
```

Comment: Where are you using the Bucketizer function in the second part of your code? I only see the QuantileDiscretizer being used.

Comment: Second part doesn't have QuantileDiscretizer