# How compute the percentile in PySpark dataframe for each key?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, percentile

I have a PySpark dataframe consists of three columns x, y, z.

X may have multiple rows in this dataframe. How can I compute the percentile of each key in x separately?

```
+------+---------+------+
|  Name|     Role|Salary|
+------+---------+------+
|   bob|Developer|125000|
|  mark|Developer|108000|
|  carl|   Tester| 70000|
|  carl|Developer|185000|
|  carl|   Tester| 65000|
| roman|   Tester| 82000|
| simon|Developer| 98000|
|  eric|Developer|144000|
|carlos|   Tester| 75000|
| henry|Developer|110000|
+------+---------+------+
```

The output needed:

```
+------+---------+------+---------+
|  Name|     Role|Salary|      50%|
+------+---------+------+---------+
|   bob|Developer|125000|117500.0 |
|  mark|Developer|108000|117500.0 |
|  carl|   Tester| 70000|72500.0  |
|  carl|Developer|185000|117500.0 |
|  carl|   Tester| 65000|72500.0  |
| roman|   Tester| 82000|72500.0  |
| simon|Developer| 98000|117500.0 |
|  eric|Developer|144000|117500.0 |
|carlos|   Tester| 75000|72500.0  |
| henry|Developer|110000|117500.0 |
+------+---------+------+---------+
```

Comment: @, I dont have idea how it will be the output, im just looking to split the role into several range. What i mean by split, is to take for example the developer between [0-25% of the developer salary], then [25-50%], [50-75%] and [75%-100%]. Im doing that because i have a huge dataframe and i nedd to know (filter) for example the developper with high salary, etc

Comment: You need to take the time to figure out what you want the output to be, and describe it in detail. What you're saying in your most recent comment and what you're asking in the question appear to be two different things. As it stands, this question may be closed as "Too Broad" or "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: You may want to look into [Difference between QuantileDiscretizer and Bucketizer in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43386188/difference-between-quantilediscretizer-and-bucketizer-in-spark)

Comment: @pault thank for the suggested links. May be I was not clear

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `groupby` + `F.expr`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.groupby('Role').agg(F.expr('percentile(Salary, array(0.25))')[0].alias('%25'),
                             F.expr('percentile(Salary, array(0.50))')[0].alias('%50'),
                             F.expr('percentile(Salary, array(0.75))')[0].alias('%75'))
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|     Role|     %25|     %50|     %75|
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|   Tester| 68750.0| 72500.0| 76750.0|
|Developer|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now you might join `df1` with the original dataframe:

```
df.join(df1, on='Role', how='left').show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|     Role|  Name|Salary|     %25|     %50|     %75|
+---------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|   Tester|  carl| 70000| 68750.0| 72500.0| 76750.0|
|   Tester|  carl| 65000| 68750.0| 72500.0| 76750.0|
|   Tester| roman| 82000| 68750.0| 72500.0| 76750.0|
|   Tester|carlos| 75000| 68750.0| 72500.0| 76750.0|
|Developer|   bob|125000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
|Developer|  mark|108000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
|Developer|  carl|185000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
|Developer| simon| 98000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
|Developer|  eric|144000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
|Developer| henry|110000|108500.0|117500.0|139250.0|
+---------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was what im looking for  with a small difference, how can get the values attached directly to the orignal datframe.  please look the updated post

Comment: One option is to `join` the resulting dataframe with the original one. Another option might be using `window` function. Check updated answer please :)

Answer (score 5):

`array` is not really necessary:

```
F.expr('percentile(Salary, 0.5)')
```

Together with window function it does the job:

```py
df = df.withColumn('50%', F.expr('percentile(Salary, 0.5)').over(W.partitionBy('Role')))

df.show()
#  +------+---------+------+--------+
#  |  Name|     Role|Salary|     50%|
#  +------+---------+------+--------+
#  |   bob|Developer|125000|117500.0|
#  |  mark|Developer|108000|117500.0|
#  |  carl|Developer|185000|117500.0|
#  | simon|Developer| 98000|117500.0|
#  |  eric|Developer|144000|117500.0|
#  | henry|Developer|110000|117500.0|
#  |  carl|   Tester| 70000| 72500.0|
#  |  carl|   Tester| 65000| 72500.0|
#  | roman|   Tester| 82000| 72500.0|
#  |carlos|   Tester| 75000| 72500.0|
#  +------+---------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, I think it's very neat and probably faster than my `groupby+join` solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `approxQuantile` function available in spark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html

Comment: This function works for the whole column. I m looking for each key to get its percentile

Comment: @bib then using this function after a groupBy on the column x?