# Groupby and percentage distributions pyspark equivalent of given pandas code

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, percentile

Whenever I want to get distributions in pandas for my entire dataset I just run the following basic code:

```
x.groupby('y').describe(percentiles=[.1, .25, .5, .75, .9, 1])
```

where I get the distribution values for every custom percentage I want. I want to do the exact same thing in pyspark. However, from what I have read the describe function in pyspark does not allow to specify percentages and the summary function in pyspark only allows for standard values of 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 so I can't customize to the percentiles I would like.

How do I do the equivalent of the pandas code below but in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [percentile_approx](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) on all column names you need (note that we drop the column we are performing the groupby on):

```
all_aggregations = []
for col in sparkDF.drop('y').columns:
    all_aggregations.extend(
        [F.percentile_approx(col, 0.1).alias(f'{col}_perc_10'),
        F.percentile_approx(col, 0.25).alias(f'{col}_perc_25'),
        F.percentile_approx(col, 0.50).alias(f'{col}_perc_50'),
        F.percentile_approx(col, 0.75).alias(f'{col}_perc_75'),
        F.percentile_approx(col, 0.90).alias(f'{col}_perc_90'),
        F.max(col).alias(f'{col}_max')]
    )

sparkDF_summary_stats = sparkDF.groupby('y').agg(
    *all_aggregations
)
```

For anyone using an earlier version of Pyspark, you can calculate percentiles using `F.expr` (credit goes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432092/5327068) by @Ala Tarighati):

```
all_aggregations = []
for col in sparkDF.drop('y').columns:
    all_aggregations.extend(
        [F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0.10))').alias(f'{col}_perc_10'),
        F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0.25))').alias(f'{col}_perc_25'),
        F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0.50))').alias(f'{col}_perc_50'),
        F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0.75))').alias(f'{col}_perc_75'),
        F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0.90))').alias(f'{col}_perc_90'),
        F.max(col).alias(f'{col}_max')]
    )

sparkDF_summary_stats = sparkDF.groupby('y').agg(
        *all_aggregations
    )
```

Using a random sample pyspark dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
random_cols = np.random.choice(sparkDF_summary_stats.columns, 4).tolist()
sparkDF_summary_stats.select(
    random_cols
).show()

+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|         col60_max|    col100_perc_75|      col37_perc_25|      col68_perc_50|
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|0.9888405413036631|0.7153223105291356| 0.3924451074226354|0.23228965409645264|
|0.9546663568790689|0.7837917844853972|0.26496706155544303| 0.4975660833887259|
|0.9969494174116696|0.6553831994634532|0.31725917435686757|0.43747492202372906|
|0.9919627472386433|0.7804711383801549|0.32662190574800876| 0.3862363952990896|
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: do you by any chance know why the comments under here were deleted? Was wondering if we can get them back. I forget why I keep getting [] type lists in the output, I think it was discussed earlier here

Comment: @bernando_vialli oh that's unfortunate – it might be stackoverflow trying to reduce clutter from long, extended comment threads. could it be from trying to apply percentile to a non-numeric column, like a field that's a string or datetime?

Comment: actually ignore my last question. I made a minor change by removing {} and that fixed it. I do have a different question though. How do I modify the above code if I want to do something similar but slightly different. If I now want to aggregate by all these percentiles (10, 25, etc) and get a mean/median value of a different column variable? In other words I want to aggregate by these same percentiles by all the variables in my dataset but the output for each of them not to be the corresponding percentile value of each of the variables but the mean/median values of one fixed specific variable

Comment: @bernando_vialli would you mind asking this as a new question? i think this is sufficiently different from this question that it deserves its own question and could help other people. i'm also not quite clear about what you're asking so asking a new question will give you more room to explain than in a comments thread (that might end up getting deleted), and ideally you could provide an example as well (like expected input and output for a toy dataset with 2 variables)

Comment: yes definitely just posted it a few minutes ago, hope it makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376453/how-to-group-by-percentile-distributions-for-every-variable-in-a-dataset-and-out