# How to group by percentile distributions for every variable in a dataset and output the mean/median in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I asked a fairly similar yet different question and got a good response here:

[Groupby and percentage distributions pyspark equivalent of given pandas code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204684/groupby-and-percentage-distributions-pyspark-equivalent-of-given-pandas-code/77205351?noredirect=1#comment136409411_77205351)

I am not sure how to tailor the modification I need to do for my current need.

What I would like to do is to create a separate group by each of the percentiles and the aggregate for each of the percentiles to be a mean & median value of a certain fixed variable (it would be the same variable for every percentile). Here is the illustration for what I have in mind (just to make sure it's clear, those variables on the left currently exist on a variable level like "age", "income", I don't have them already created in advance with the percentiles, that's part of what I need to create.

```
                         mean(credit score)     median(credit score)
age_10th_percentile        700                       550
age_25th_percentile        710                       560
age_50th_percentile        750                       580
income_10th_percentile     710                       590
income_25th_percentile     730                       610
income_50th_percentile     740                       640
```

Comment: is the interpretation of the row `age_10th_percentile` supposed to be that we calculate the mean and median credit scores of everyone in the 10th percentile or below?

Comment: what is your input data set?

Comment: Happy to contribute to this Q !

Comment: @Derek O, yes you are exactly correct in your interpretation. Doof, not sure if I understand the question but the input dataset is just raw values for each of these variables like age, income, credit score etc etc (not aggregated)

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula this is pyspark

Comment: @Derek O, any ideas on this one?

Comment: @bernando_vialli i'm quite busy at the moment, but happy to circle back on this tomorrow!

Comment: @Derek O, thank you so much!

Comment: @DerekO, sorry to bug you about this (I of course need to somehow get your skillset in pyspark), was just curios if you got a chance to look into this?

Comment: @bernando_vialli sure i'll let you know what i figure out!

Answer (score 0):

The format of the output dataframe(s) won't be the same as what you have written in your question because pyspark doesn't really have the concept of an index. However, you can to first calculate the percentiles of each `col`, use this to bin your data accordingly, and then calculate the mean and median of any other columns using those bins.

We start out with a sample pyspark dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('percentileAggregations').getOrCreate()

np.random.seed(42)
col1 = 100 + 50*np.random.rand(100)
col2 = 200 + 50*np.random.rand(100)
col3 = 300 + 50*np.random.rand(100)
col4 = 400 + 50*np.random.rand(100)
col5 = 500 + 50*np.random.rand(100)

pandasDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': col1,
    'col2': col2,
    'col3': col3,
    'col4': col4,
    'col5': col5,
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF)

+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              col1|              col2|              col3|              col4|              col5|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|118.72700594236812|201.57145928433673| 332.1015823077144| 402.5840860584304|505.15619344179663|
| 147.5357153204958|  231.820520563189| 304.2069982497524| 426.5677315784074| 545.1276453339783|
|136.59969709057026|215.71779905381632|308.08143570473067| 427.0317560805053| 525.2626186223929|
|129.93292420985182|225.42853455823513|344.92770942635394|431.87149507491034| 541.3228733053871|
|107.80093202212183|245.37832369630465| 330.3214529829795|436.30456668613306| 516.0024800515306|
|107.79972601681013|212.46461145744374|300.45985258083147|448.79260397312675|   544.77616142481|
|102.90418060840997|220.51914615178148| 305.0735771433016|425.81501741505974| 519.4600839367082|
...
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Then we calculate the percentiles of each column, and use these values to assign buckets with a udf:

```
## calculate percentiles, note this will be one row

all_percentiles = [
    F.expr(f'percentile({col}, array(0, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50))').alias(f'{col}_percentiles')
    for col in df.columns
]

df_percentiles = df.select(
    *all_percentiles
)

percentiles_row = df_percentiles.collect()[0]

percentile_info = {
    f'{col}_percentiles': percentiles_row[f'{col}_percentiles']
     for col in df.columns
}

def categorizer(bins, value):
  if bins[0] <= value <= bins[1]:
    return "10th"
  elif bins[1] < value <= bins[2]:
    return "25th"
  elif bins[2] < value <= bins[3]:
    return "50th"
  else: 
    return "above_50th"

def bucket_udf(bins):
    return F.udf(lambda l: categorizer(bins, l))

df_percentile_buckets = df.select('*')

for col in df.columns:
    df_percentile_buckets = df_percentile_buckets.withColumn(
        f"{col}_buckets", bucket_udf(percentile_info[f"{col}_percentiles"])(F.col(col))
    )
```

This gives us the following:

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|              col1|              col2|              col3|              col4|              col5|col1_buckets|col2_buckets|col3_buckets|col4_buckets|col5_buckets|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|118.72700594236812|201.57145928433673| 332.1015823077144| 402.5840860584304|505.15619344179663|        50th|        10th|  above_50th|        10th|        25th|
| 147.5357153204958|  231.820520563189| 304.2069982497524| 426.5677315784074| 545.1276453339783|  above_50th|  above_50th|        10th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
|136.59969709057026|215.71779905381632|308.08143570473067| 427.0317560805053| 525.2626186223929|  above_50th|        50th|        25th|  above_50th|        50th|
|129.93292420985182|225.42853455823513|344.92770942635394|431.87149507491034| 541.3228733053871|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
|107.80093202212183|245.37832369630465| 330.3214529829795|436.30456668613306| 516.0024800515306|        25th|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|        50th|
|107.79972601681013|212.46461145744374|300.45985258083147|448.79260397312675|   544.77616142481|        25th|        50th|        10th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
|102.90418060840997|220.51914615178148| 305.0735771433016|425.81501741505974| 519.4600839367082|        10th|        50th|        25th|  above_50th|        50th|
|143.30880728874675|237.77755692715243| 333.1750884554028| 416.1478236470623| 500.5418825740149|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|        50th|        10th|
|130.05575058716045|211.43990827458111| 300.2530791923109| 439.7593097384352| 545.2690988209632|  above_50th|        25th|        10th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
| 135.4036288898023|203.84899549143964|308.04040257087496|413.54161256310374| 504.5643338393067|  above_50th|        10th|        25th|        50th|        25th|
|101.02922471479012| 214.4875726456884| 327.4366894683293| 421.9485710352818| 515.9656818795207|        10th|        50th|        50th|        50th|        50th|
| 148.4954926080997|208.06106436270022|334.59475988463464| 403.9228190671133| 547.5030983525403|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|
|141.62213204002109|246.48488261712865|   332.59806297513|401.26753717077287| 547.5303573468778|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|        10th|  above_50th|
|110.61695553391381|240.40601897822086|  311.213465473028|448.13242073389625| 528.6718944061643|        50th|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
|109.09124836035502|231.67018782552117| 335.6089610673768| 441.7990060256103| 531.5918606084899|        25th|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|
|109.17022549267169| 243.5730295093859|   311.86245437484| 434.7987103046849|  522.422276098916|        25th|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|        50th|
|115.21211214797688| 240.1836038449557|316.26998490796336| 420.4476472207135| 514.6605385849032|        50th|  above_50th|        50th|        50th|        50th|
| 126.2378215816119| 209.3285029443018| 337.3245702559012| 408.6647160035423| 516.4332272684958|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|        25th|        50th|
| 121.5972509321058| 244.6279499244989|332.48164495236074|407.82185213355433|  533.625922803852|        50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|        25th|  above_50th|
| 114.5614570099021|226.96711209578254| 342.4611705247089|412.51214490822974|  537.618726471884|        50th|  above_50th|  above_50th|        50th|  above_50th|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Then we can calculate metrics separately for any column based on the buckets of another column using `groupby`. For example below we calculate the mean and median of `col2` based on the buckets of `col1`:

```
df_col_based_metrics = df_percentile_buckets.groupby(
    'col1_buckets'
).agg(
    F.mean('col2').alias('mean_col2'),
    F.percentile_approx('col2', 0.50).alias('median_col2'),
)

+------------+------------------+------------------+
|col1_buckets|         mean_col2|       median_col2|
+------------+------------------+------------------+
|        10th|223.64443638995675|220.51914615178148|
|        50th|227.48628498873842|230.47821669899486|
|        25th| 225.8940829666104|231.67018782552117|
|  above_50th| 223.5429176531586|220.87055015743894|
+------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this on Monday when accessing my work computer but in the meantime, is this generalizable to hundreds of columns? The 2 I listed were just for illustration purposes since I see some of your code is variable by variable

Comment: @bernando_vialli it should be possible, but we will need to restructure some of the code. also for hundreds of columns, it's ugly to use hundreds of bucketizers and apply the transform hundreds of times – you may be better off just writing a custom udf function that does the same thing as the bucketizer. also you will end up with as many metric dfs as there are columns – you might consider storing these in a dictionary

Comment: thank you. I guess 2 things I am not sure about. 1) I can't use percentile_approx for the same reason as in the original question you answered, presumably I can replace with .expr as in the other question? 2) The point I mentioned above, how would I create the custom udf you reference? Also, I have some questions on the actual code you created might take too much space to write. a) What is the purpose of the + float(int)? b) What is percentiles_row = df_percentiles.collect()[0] accomplishing? c) What is df_bucketed = income_bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep") etc accomplishing?

Comment: @bernando_vialli 1) you should be able to use `.expr` as in the other question, and 2) i think i can answer all the questions by explaining the purpose of bucketing. let's say we know that 0th, 10th, 25th, and 50th income percentiles are `[10k, 30k, 70k, 100k]`. then we apply this to each row of the income column to create a new column called `income_percentile` where any rows where the income is between 10k and 30k is "10th_percentile" representing income between 0th and 10th percentile, any row between 30k and 70k is "25th percentile", etc this is what all of the bucketizer functions are for

Comment: I guess I mean like more of each of these individual steps what each of them are accomplishing individually? But the bigger question is on the udf function, how would I go about doing that? I would think I need to create a for loop to iterate through all the columns instead of having each individual variable have the aggregation and groupby functions but I am not sure how to create a for loop and combine that with aspects of the code you have created

Comment: @bernando_vialli i've restructured the code so that it's generalizable for any number of columns, and also uses a `udf` instead the `bucketizer` as I think it simplifies the code and makes it more readable

Comment: thank you very much for this! When I run this part of the code I seem to get an error message: df_percentile_buckets = df.withColumn({
    f"{col}_buckets": bucket_udf(percentile_info[f"{col}_percentiles"])(F.col(col))
    for col in df.columns
}) I get: TypeError: withColumn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'. Any idea why?

Comment: @bernando_vialli oh that's a typo, it should be `df.withColumns` and not `df.withColumn`

Comment: when I do .withColumns it gives me AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumns'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255871/discussion-between-derek-o-and-bernando-vialli).

Comment: if I start commenting in the chat do you get notifications for it? Since I have used the chat feature no more then a few times I am not sure how it works. I know that you wrote a comment there 2 days ago and I only saw it now when I clicked on the link (I responded back too)

Comment: I posted some follow questions in our detail chat below, figured you probably don't get a notification when I message in the chat window